# Increase page timeout from inside a web part

Tags: file-upload, time-out

We have a webpart that allows users to upload videos to YouTube. In testing, we were able to exceed the script timeout. I believe the default is 120 seconds.

Can this setting be changed / accommodated inside the web part, or can this only be changed in the web.config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SPLongOperation` for this kind of stuff:

http://nikspatel.wordpress.com/2011/04/27/use-splongoperation-to-display-sharepoint-processing-page-for-lengthy-operations/

Comment: Yes, thanks, I've seen that technique mentioned. Unfortunately this is for a branding site - and I doubt the client would be happy with that dialog. Can the dialog be changed?

Comment: This looks a little more fine-grained http://ruudheemskerk.net/archive/2009/11/24/long-operations-in-sharepoint-part-2.aspx

Comment: Yep, that's how you would have to the change the dialog, by inheriting that class.